# Cut A Shape Into Two Triangles

Tags: triangles, geometry

I have this shape:
[image: Shape],
and I want to put a straight line somewhere through the shape to cut it into two triangles. I know that this is possible, but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a line segment, there are three exhaustive, mutually exclusive cases:

Case $1$: Both endpoints of the line segment lie on a side of the original shape.

Case $2$: One endpoint of the line segment lies on a vertex, and the other endpoint lies on a side.

Case $3$: Both endpoints of the line segment lie on a vertex of the original shape.

If you can split this figure into two triangles with a single line segment, the resulting two triangles must share a side and have $4$ vertices between them (without double-counting).  Given these cases, is this ever possible?

---

Another way to think about it:

You can think about the problem as bringing two triangles together, and those two triangles must share a side (which is the line segment you draw).  Bringing any two triangles together in such a way results in a larger shape that has $4$ vertices, but the original shape here has $5$.

Comment: yes, it is a Mathematical Olympiad question in China.

Comment: Well that grabs my attention.  In that case, if someone can point out an error in my reasoning, I'll happily delete  my response.  It simply doesn't seem possible to me as is, though.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to me either...

Comment: It just can't be possible.  You can think about it as bringing two triangles together, and those two triangles must share a side (which is the line segment you draw).  Bringing any two triangles together in such a way results in a larger shape that has $4$ vertices, but the original shape here has $5$.

Comment: @KajHansen There is a minor flaw in that argument, which is that the triangles don't necessarily need to share an entire side.  However, it seems certain that the resulting shape, while having as many as 6 sides, wouldn't be convex as in the question, so it still seems impossible.

Comment: I found a way, look at answers

Comment: @ErickWong, I considered what you are saying, but since the line segment itself is supposed to divide the region into two disjoint triangles whose union is the original shape, then the line segment itself must be a whole side of both triangles - i.e. the two triangles will share a side.